# Derivatives of Logarithmic function

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Determine $f'(x)$ for $f(x) = ln(x + \sqrt{x^2 + 1})$

My handbook has the answer as $\displaystyle\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + 1}}$ with no steps on how they got there.

I tried to get there, but somewhere I am getting things wrong. This is what I have

\begin{align}
f'(x) & = \displaystyle\frac{1}{x + \sqrt{x^2 + 1}}\cdot\tfrac{d}{dx}(x + \sqrt{x^2 + 1})\\
& = \displaystyle\frac{\tfrac{1}{x + \sqrt{x^2 + 1}} \cdot\tfrac{d}{dx}(x + \sqrt{x^2 + 1})}{x + \sqrt{x^2 + 1}}\\
& = \displaystyle\frac{\tfrac{1}{x + \sqrt{x^2 + 1}} \cdot (1 + \tfrac{d}{dx}(x^2 + 1)^{\tfrac{1}{2}})}{x + \sqrt{x^2 + 1}} \\
& = \displaystyle\frac{\tfrac{1}{x + \sqrt{x^2 + 1}} \cdot (1 + \tfrac{1}{2}(\tfrac{d}{dx}x^2 + 0)^{-\tfrac{1}{2}})}{x + \sqrt{x^2 + 1}} \\
& = \displaystyle\frac{\tfrac{1}{x + \sqrt{x^2 + 1}} \cdot (1 + \tfrac{1}{2}(2x)^{-\tfrac{1}{2}})}{x + \sqrt{x^2 + 1}} \\
& = \displaystyle\frac{\tfrac{1}{x + \sqrt{x^2 + 1}} \cdot (1 + \tfrac{1}{2\sqrt{2x}})}{x + \sqrt{x^2 + 1}} \\
& = \displaystyle\frac{\tfrac{1}{x + \sqrt{x^2 + 1}}  + \tfrac{2\sqrt{2x}}{x + \sqrt{x^2 + 1}}}{x + \sqrt{x^2 + 1}} \\
\end{align}

Here I gave up, I have a mistake, but I can't figure out where

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why, in your second line, did you divide the derivative by $$x + \sqrt{x^2 + 1}\;\;?$$
Your first step is correct:
$$f'(x)=\displaystyle\frac{1}{x + \sqrt{x^2 + 1}}\cdot\tfrac{d}{dx}(x + \sqrt{x^2 + 1})$$
But when we take the derivative of $x + \sqrt{x^2 + 1} = x + (x^2 + 1)^{1/2},$ we get

$$f'(x) = \dfrac 1{x+\sqrt{x^2 + 1}}\cdot \underbrace{\left(1 + \require{cancel}\dfrac{\cancel{2}x}{\cancel{2}(x^2 + 1)^{1/2}}\right)}_{\frac d{dx} \left(x + (x^2 + 1)^{1/2}\right)}$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: It took some staring, but I see I also forgot to apply the chain rule.

Comment: Does it make sense now, Leon?

Comment: Loads more, thanks :) Calculus has a bad reputation, when all else fails, remember to apply the rules

Answer (score 1):

Using the chain rule: set u = x + (x^2 + 1)^(1/2) ==> du/dx = 1 + x/(x^2 + 1)^(1/2) =

= (x + (x^2 + 1)^1/2)/(x^2 + 1)^1/2, and dy/du = 1/u = 1/(x + (x^2 + 1)^1/2). So:

dy/dx = dy/du*du/dx = 1/(x^2 + 1)^1/2.